# How to change the quantity of feeds in custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, feed

I created a custom post type "podcast" and all podcasts are inside it. when I visit `http://example.com/?feed=podcast`, it only shows latest 10 podcasts. How do I change it to 99?

I googled and found the code below:

```
function feedFilter($query) {
if (is_feed()) {
    $query->set('posts_per_page','30');
}
return $query;}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'feedFilter');
```

It doesn't work.

How to customize the feed items quantity in a custom post type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file where the `pre_get_posts` action runs is `wp-includes/query.php`, If we look in that file, we'll see that *after* the action is executed, the `posts_per_page` setting is overridden for feeds with this bit of code:

```
if ( $this->is_feed ) {
    $q['posts_per_page'] = get_option('posts_per_rss');
    $q['nopaging'] = false;
}
```

In this case, we can add a filter to the value of `posts_per_rss` to customize the feed quantity that way.

```
function feed_action( $query ){
    if( $query->is_feed( 'podcast' ) ) {
        add_filter( 'option_posts_per_rss', 'feed_posts' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'feed_action' );

function feed_posts(){
    return 99;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `post_limits` filter for feeds, or From backend you should be able to manage post count for feed:

[image]

Just change it to number of posts in `Syndication feeds` you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

your code is almost correct.
I've modified somewhat.

```
function feedFilter($query) {
   if (is_feed()) {
     $query->set('posts_per_page','30');
   }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'feedFilter');
```

Above should work