# WordPress feed only shows first page of category

Tags: custom-post-types, rss, feed

I'm having an issue with the WordPress feed for a custom post type I have. When I go to my feed at:

`www.mysite.com/feed/?post_type=type`

I get only the first 10 posts, not the full list. I basically only get the latest posts on that first page.

Has anyone experienced this before? How do I get the full list of posts in that category?

Answer (score 0):

The number of items within a feed can be changed in the admin area under:

**Settings > Reading > Syndication feeds show the most recent**

Changing the settings above will affect all feeds. If you want to change the number of posts only for a particular post type, you can add the following code to your `functions.php` file, changing `post_type_name` to your post type's name ([Source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128814/how-to-change-the-quantity-of-feeds-in-custom-post-type) for this trick).

```
function wpse240469_feed_posts( $query ){
    if ( $query->is_main_query() &&
         $query->is_feed() &&
         'post_type_name' === $query->query_vars['post_type'] 
    ) {
        add_filter( 'option_posts_per_rss', 'wpse240469_feed_number_posts' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse240469_feed_posts' );

function wpse240469_feed_number_posts(){
    return -1; // -1 for all posts, change to whatever value you want
}
```